# JDBC and MySQL: Do changes in the underlying database are known to the java program?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

Suppose that, *after I establish a connection* of my java application with my underlying MySQL database, and then open *MySQL workbench and update some rows in a table,* and then *retrieve the fields of that table in the java client*, will those changes synchronize with the java program. In other words, **will those changes appear in the results of queries I carry out in the java program?**

**In general, after establishing a connection between a java application and a MySQL database, are the updates, deletions, alterations etc. carried out in the database by using the MySQL DBMS (and not the java program) visible to the program?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if you run your query again.

Specifically, if you run something like this:

```
ResultSet resultSet = myStatement.executeQuery("select * from some_table");
```

and then you update the database (either from the command line / database client), then no. you will need to run your query again to see the changes you made.

Answer (score 2):

In general, yes.

If they are not showing up, my first guess would be that you are not `commit`ing the updates in the workbench